# Need help understanding a proof on sets of divergence

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, harmonic-analysis, characteristic-functions

I have few questions regarding the proof to the theorem : ( Katznelson "An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis" Chapter 2.3

[image]

[image]

What I am struggeling to understand is the last bit of the proof:

Why does $ \hat{X}(j)=0 $ implies that $X(t)= $ constant almost everywhere?
Is this a general property of fourier-transformed characteristic functions?
And why does that imply that $ \tilde{E} $ is either zero or $ 2 \pi$?

Then I I don't see why $ T \backslash \tilde{E} $ is a Set of divergence of measure zero and $ \tilde{E} $ is a set of divergence,hence $T$ is a set of divergence.

I tried looking up different things about characteristic functions on measures, could't find anything regarding my question. 
Thank you for any help in advance !

Comment: look up fourier inversion. also, "Then I I don't see why ∖̃  is a Set of divergence of measure zero and ̃  is a set of divergence,hence  is a set of divergence." This is ridiculous. There are about 4 claims/implications in that statement. What *precisely* do you not understand.

Comment: What is 'condition  3.4'?